# How can i see a log of internet connectiones using command prompt?

Tags: command-line

OK, i know there is a way you can get command prompt to display a log of what programs connect to the internet and stuff, but i don't know what the command is. I'm using windows vista.

Comment: You mean the present programs that are connected to the network ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
netstat -a
```

use `netstat /?` in the command prompt for help on this command and to see other options of this command